# ARM cross compiled ZeroMQ zstr_rcv() gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, pipe, zeromq

I cross-compiled `zmq` and `czmq` for ARM (`arm-poky-linux`) to build a PUB-SUB message router. In the program, I fork a attached thread using `zthread_fork()` and talk through the pipe. When I do a `zstr_rcv()` from main after forking, i get a segmentation fault. This code works fine in my Ubuntu box with GCC. What am I doing wrong here? or is it a ARM compatibility issue?

Below is a simple code snippet.

```c
//  listener thread function.  
static void listener_thread (void *args, zctx_t *ctx, void *pipe)
{
    //  Send sync message to main().
    zstr_send (pipe, "READY");

    //  Do work.
    while (1)
    {
        sleep (1);
    }
}


//  main() forks the listener thread and waits for the sync message from the listener with zstr_rcv().
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    //  Create a ZeroMQ context.
    zctx_t *context = zctx_new();
    assert (context);

    //  Deploy the listner.
    void *listener = zthread_fork (context, listener_thread, NULL);
    assert (listener);

    //  Wait for the sync signal.
    char *string = zstr_recv (listener);
    zstr_free (&string);

    //  Do stuff here.
    while (1)
    {
        sleep (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zstr):

```
//  Receive C string from socket. Caller must free returned string using
//  zstr_free(). Returns NULL if the context is being terminated or the
//  process was interrupted.
CZMQ_EXPORT char *
    zstr_recv (void *source);
```

Note how the suggestion is to use `zstr_free()` instead of `free()`.  You might just be getting away with a bad behavior on your Ubuntu desktop by luck.  Try the suggested freeing method and see if that works better

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, my bad there but it's not the cause. I changed it to use `zstr_free` but still the segmentation fault is there.

Comment: As per my answer below, this was a brain fart at my end. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a case of mismatched library versions. Instead of the required `libzmq.so.3` for czmq, I have used `libzmq.so.4`. Once the correct versions were used, everything was well.

On a brighter note, hope others will learn from this. Apologies for the confusion created.